# Elementor & Wordpress display primary category taxonomy terms only

Tags: wordpress, elementor, custom-taxonomy

Is it possible to display only the Primary category term on Elementor?
I have custom post types and taxonomies created and I have the Taxonomy Video and then Sub ones like Video Editing, and I would like to show only Video Editing which is the primary category.

[image: elementor taxonomy]

Answer (score 0):

These items should have a class tag id attached to them when displayed. CSS hide that tag should allow you to hide it cosmetically.

You can also build your own template loop to have full control over what you want ( might need the Elementor pro or anywhere Elementor extension )

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have Elementor PRO and I did create a template loop but when I pull the taxonomy terms it doesn't display only the primary one...guessing it's WP default behavior.

Comment: can you show the output html for the tags? it should be something like "<span class="tagid- " I meant you can css hide the tag you dont want to display.

Comment: Yes I know that, but Elementor doesn't add an ID for each..this is what I have for each of them :"class="elementor-post-info__terms-list-item"

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the second occurrence forward by adding the following code:

```css
.elementor-post-info__terms-list-item:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none !important;
}
```